# Чтение байтов по сокету

Tags: java, сокет

Надо написать сервер который будет считывать байты на входе, данный код не работает, клиент отправляет байты, а он не считывает.
Выводит только размер и дальше зависает, ничего не показывает и цикл не завершает, зависает на повторном считывании `outputStream.write(data, 0, length);`
Почему так?

```
public static final int PORT = 4445;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Welcome to Server side");
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;

    ServerSocket servers = null;
    Socket fromclient = null;

    // create server socket

    try {
        servers = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't listen to port 4445");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    try {
        System.out.print("Waiting for a client...");
        fromclient = servers.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't accept");
        System.exit(-1);
    }


    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int length = 0;
    in = fromclient.getInputStream();

    while ((length = in.read(data)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(data, 0, length);
        System.out.println(length);
    }
    System.out.println(2);
    System.out.println(outputStream.toString());

    String input, output;

    System.out.println("Wait for messages");

    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
        out.println("You have wrote for me " + input);
        System.out.println(input);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    fromclient.close();
    servers.close();
}
```

Comment: У вас цикл чтения будет крутиться, пока входной поток не закончится (не отключится клиент). Нужно как-то разбирать данные, пришедшие от клиента, и определять, что клиент все передал и ждет ответа (например использовать `BufferedReader.readLine`, если клиент завершает каждую посылку переводом строки, или `DataInputStream` для приема и `DataOutputStream` для передачи, используя парные методы `readXXX/writeXXX` в одинаковом порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Вот судя по всему Ваш камень преткновения:

[BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) - предназначен для символьного вывода/ввода

[InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) -чтение и запись двоичных данных

```
BufferedReader in = null; 
// 
in = fromclient.getInputStream();
```

**UPD**: тогда продолжу.Проблемный участок кода:

```
while ((length = in.read(data)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(data, 0, length);
        System.out.println(length);
    }
```

Вы не проверяя доступны ли в стриме биты пытаетесь считать их.

> метод in.available()
>
> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or
>   skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next
>   caller of a method for this input stream. The next caller might be
>   the same thread or another thread.  A single read or skip of this
>   many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.

Вот шаблон решения которое будет вычитывать биты.

```
    byte[] data = null;
    int length = -1;
    in = new DataInputStream(fromclient.getInputStream());
    while (true) {
        if ((length = in.available()) > 0) {
            data = new byte[length];
            in.readFully(data, 0, length);
            outputStream.write(data, 0, length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: да этот код менял здесь, там на самом деле написан сейчас InputStream

Comment: На самом деле в коде написано InputStream

Comment: Дополнил ответ.